# Transformation between Bessel and ETRS

Tags: coordinate-system

I have the following problem in ArcGIS:
for a species distribution model I need environmental layers and occurrence points. 
The problem is my occurrence data points are in **ETRS_89_UTM_Zone_32N** and some of my layers are in the some, but others are in **GCS_Bessel_1841**. Obviously its not very easy to transform between these two, I struggled even after using google for some time now.

How do I transform or project everything into one format?

For the occurrence data I need x/y coordinates.

Comment: Are you sure with the name GCS_Bessel_1981, i only find GCS_Bessel_1841?

Comment: Oh no... Sorry! :-) I confused it, yes, you are right. Its GCS_Bessel_1841! I edited my post.

Comment: As pointed out, Bessel 1841 is an ellipsoid (spheroid), not a true geodetic datum or coordinate reference system. If the data is in Germany, redefine it as DHDN (Deutsches Hauptdreiecksnetz). then you'll get transformations. If the data's elsewhere, please edit question with the location.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcMap you can use the Toolbox command Project under Data Management and then Projections and Transformations. I assume you want all your coordinates projected?
Then you are transforming from a GCS (Bessel) to a PCS (UTM) which is based on a different GCS (ETRS), an additional transformation between these (Bessel->ETRS) is required. But you can leave it out and let ArcGIS find a good transformation. They are very similar anyway.

Comment: I tried to found a transformation on the geographic_transformations_1031 document of ESRI and I couldn't. Most likely their none for this transformation...

Comment: You are right, i tried to transform some example points, but the coordinate values didn't change. So if it should be very exact, you can't do it inside arcis: see my comment to your answer. Using http://sgs.geodatenzentrum.de/coordtrans/ you can transform from GEO_DHDN (Bessel) to GEO_ETRS89 (ETRS).

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken the details of the systems are:

-ETRS_89_UTM_Zone_32N has WKID:25832 and it is a projected coordinate system

-GCS_Bessel_1841 has WKID:4004 and it is a geographic coordinate system.

In order to transform between them you will have to create your own transformation using the parameters found in the below links (or in other similar websites):

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-utm-zone-32n/html/

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4004/html/

Please note that the GCS_Bessel_1841 is *"Unknown datum based upon the Bessel 1841 ellipsoid"*. I am not sure if you will manage to make the transformation successfully and it will definitely be much less accurate than the other one.

Comment: You could use dhdn, which is basically a bessel GCS. Or try it with an online service like this one (in german): http://sgs.geodatenzentrum.de/coordtrans/

Comment: That was it!!! A dhdn worked just fine. Thank you Andreas!!!